# `timedelta` object not accounting for daylight savings

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, dst

I am trying to get the appropriate time range to query in a database (where datetimes are stored in UTC) in the local timezone of a user. Here's some odd behavior that I'm finding that I don't know how to work around:

```py
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

local_tz = pytz.timezone("America/New_York")
utc = pytz.timezone("UTC")

start = local_tz.localize(datetime(2019, 11, 3))  # 2019-11-03 00:00:00-04:00
end = start + timedelta(days=1)  # 2019-11-04 00:00:00-04:00

start_utc = utc.normalize(start)  # 2019-11-03 04:00:00+00:00
end_utc = utc.normalize(end)  # 2019-11-04 04:00:00+00:00

utc.normalize(local_tz.localize(datetime(2019, 11, 4)))  # 2019-11-04 05:00:00+00:00
```

The Daylight savings change is lost somehow when normalizing the `end` variable contstructed by adding a `timedelta` object to `start`. Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the expected behavior on the datetime calculations, but I'll just explain the behavior from shared code samples.

`pytz.localize` creates a timezone aware datetime instance. When NY timezone is used to `localize` the naive datetime, it assigns the correct timezone, `EDT` until November 3rd, and `EST` for Nevember 4th and later. Let's exclude `timedelta` here:

```
>>> import pytz
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> tz_ny = pytz.timezone("America/New_York")
>>> tz_ny.localize(datetime(2019, 11, 3))
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 3, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)
>>> tz_ny.localize(datetime(2019, 11, 4))
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 4, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' EST-1 day, 19:00:00 STD>)
```

As seen, the `DstTzInfo` are different, as one would expect, because NY DST ends on November 3rd.

The shared code sample creates `start` by `localizing` November 3rd, which assigns `EDT` as `tzinfo` to the datetime object (using DST). To create `end`, `timedelta` of 1 day is added to `start`, but the `tzinfo` of the `datetime` object is [kept untouched](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7356e10820b160d14b0ce0aba5427a8f9e757aa7/Modules/datetimemodule.c#L4097):

```
>>> start = tz_ny.localize(datetime(2019, 11, 3))
>>> start.tzinfo
<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>
>>> end = start + timedelta(days=1)
>>> end.tzinfo
<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>
```

So `end` is `datetime` for November 4th, but `DstTzInfo` info is still the same as November 3rd. And this is different than `localizing` a naive `datetime` of November 4th, which doesn't use DST.

Comment: It totally didn't register to me that the tzinfo would remain the same, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Alex that's the flaw in the `tzinfo` interface, it doesn't have a way of updating the zone object when the underlying `datetime` changes. If you can, you should do all your date arithmetic in UTC and convert when necessary.

Comment: Yeah that's what I do when I can, but in this instance I need to calculate a time range in the local timezone first then access the appropriate data in the database which is stored in UTC.